# MySQL-based wiki that is suitable for custom applications?

Tags: mysql, wiki

I develop an online, Flash-based multiplayer game.  It is a complex game, and requires a lot of documentation to fully explain it to our users.  Ideally, I would like to find MySQL-based wiki software that can provide these editable documentation pages outside of Flash (in the HTML realm) but also within Flash for convenience, and so that players can refer to the information without interrupting their game or having to switch back-and-forth between browser tabs.  I am expecting that I would need to do a lot of the work on the Flash side myself, as far as formatting, for example, but I would like to feel comfortable in querying the wiki's database to get info directly.  I guess this means that I need a wiki that is structured relatively "flat" or intuitively so that I can do things like:

1. Run a MySQL query that returns a list of all the articles (their titles and IDs) in the wiki
2. For each article ID in the wiki, return the associated content

This may mean that I have to limit the kinds of formatting I put into the wiki -- things like tables would probably be omitted since they would be very difficult, if not impossible, for me to do on the Flash side.  And that is fine!

Basically I am just looking for suggestions for wiki software that is pretty easy to use, but mostly is technically simple enough on the back-end that interfacing with it directly via MySQL is not difficult.  When interfacing with the database directly, I only need to READ data.  Any time the wiki would be edited or added to would be done via the wiki's actual front-end application.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Any reason why MediaWiki (which can use MySQL) is not appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki is the best-known and best-supported MySQL-based Wiki, used for plenty of complex game documentation projects like [MinecraftWiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Minecraft_Wiki).  The database is not all that simple, but it's [well documented](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aDatabase_layout) and basic read operations aren't too hard.  For example, here's how to fetch the current content of the page "MyPage":

```
SELECT old_text FROM page,revision,text WHERE page.page_title="MyPage" AND
  page.page_id=revision.rev_page AND revision.rev_text_id=text.old_id;
```

(And yes, `old_text` is the current content of the page. Don't ask me why!)

Your main problem will be figuring out how to parse MediaWiki markup, there are [plenty of parsers](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) for it but I'm not aware of anything that would work in Flash.